# Firebase JS Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a web app using firebase and encountered this error. After a few hours of debugging, I still haven't been able to understand what's wrong, I'll leave the code here for anyone who can help me figure out what its is that I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion will be really helpful, thanks!

**Code:**

```
    import {
      getFirestore,
      addDoc,
      doc,
      updateDoc,
      collection,
      query,
      where,
      getDocs,
      setDoc,
    } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);

var files = [....]

getDocs(collection(firestore, "property")).then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (files.includes(decrypt(doc.data().fileno))) {
        if (files.includes(decrypt(doc.data().fileno), 6)) {
          let owner = "ABC";
          const bref = doc(collection(firestore, "property"), doc.id);
          updateDoc(bref,{owner:encrypt(owner)}).then(()=>{
            console.log("updated")
          })

        } else {
          let owner = "XYZ";
          const bref = doc(collection(firestore, "property"), doc.id);
          updateDoc(bref,{owner:encrypt(owner)}).then(()=>{
            console.log("updated")
          })
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I highly recommend adding a linter to your project that alerts you to [variable shadowing](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow)

Answer (score 4):

You have two definitions of `doc` in your code:

1. The `doc` function that you import from the Firestore SDK
2. The `doc` parameter that you declare in `querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {`.

The second `doc` hides the first one, which is why you can't call the `doc` function anymore inside that callback.

The solution is to give the variable a different name, like `docSnapshot`.